# How to output assigned values in VBA

Tags: vba

could someone please help me with this pretty simple problem I am having. Basically this is a simplified code for more a more complex problem I am trying to solve. I want to be able to output the values I have assigned to a,b,c,d and e in the column b. The values I have used for a,b,c,d and e are taken from cells a1,a2,a3,a4 and a5.

Thanks :)

```
Sub help()
    Dim letters As String
    Dim count As Integer

    a = Range("a1").Value
    b = Range("a2").Value
    c = Range("a3").Value
    d = Range("a2").Value
    e = Range("a3").Value

    letters = "abcde"

    For count = 1 To Len(letters)
        Range("b" & count) = Mid(letters, count, 1)
    Next

    'HOW DO I OUTPUT THE ASSIGNED VALUES TO a,b,c,d & e RATHER THAN OUTPUTTING LETTERS?'
End Sub
```

Comment: Please explain your question. I find it unclear. If you are trying to access the value of a variable from a string containing the variable name, that isn't possible in VBA. A common work-around is to use a dictionary keyed by  e.g. `"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"` rather than separate variables such as `a,b,c,d,e`.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your advice..using dictionary was exactly what I was looking for. The exact purposes of my task are quite hard to explain, but this simplified version was enough to get the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to change your code as follows:

```
Sub help()
    a = Range("a1").Value
    b = Range("a2").Value
    c = Range("a3").Value
    d = Range("a2").Value
    e = Range("a3").Value

    Range("b1").Value = a
    Range("b2").Value = b
    Range("b3").Value = c
    Range("b4").Value = d
    Range("b5").Value = e
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could use an array instead of individual variables, e.g.

```
Sub help()
    Dim myArr(1 To 5) As Variant
    Dim count As Long
    For count = 1 To 5
        myArr(count) = Cells(count, "A").Value
    Next count    

    For count = 1 To 5
        Cells(count, "B").Value = myArr(count)
    Next count    
End Sub
```

That could also be simplified by saying:

```
Sub help()
    Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = Range("A1:A5").Value ' myArr will be a two-dimensional array
    Range("B1:B5").Value = myArr
End Sub
```

Or, as John Coleman suggested in a comment, you could use a Dictionary:

```
Sub help()
    Dim myVars As Object
    Dim letters As String
    Dim count As Long
    Set myVars = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    myVars("a") = Range("a1").Value
    myVars("b") = Range("a2").Value
    myVars("c") = Range("a3").Value
    myVars("d") = Range("a2").Value
    myVars("e") = Range("a3").Value

    letters = "abcde"

    For count = 1 To Len(letters)
        Range("b" & count) = myVars(Mid(letters, count, 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This dictionary method is perfect for my particular application. My original code was of the same structure as your first response above, but I wanted something more elegant due to the scale of my project.

Answer (score 1):

Simply turn around the assignment you made to the variable and make it go to the cell.

A couple other quick tips:

1. Also, while VBA doesn't require specific variable declarations, the implicit declared type is always `Variant`. So it's considered professional practice to declare all variables and always use `Option Explicit`.
2. Always define and set references to the workbook and worksheets.

So...

```
Sub help()
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Dim ws as Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim a as String
    a = ws.Range("A1")

    ws.Range("B1") = a
End Sub
```